# html select on change event in JavaScript does not return desired value

Tags: javascript

i've been searching in the internet for the possible solution but I can't find a possible solution. I hava a drop down list.

```
<select  id="module-box" onchange="myFunction()">
                        <option value="">Select status</option>
                        <option value="1">Pending</option>
                        <option value="2">Approved</option>
                        <option value="3">Denied</option>
                        <option value="4">All</option>
</select>
```

And here's my javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("module-box").value;
     if(x==1){
        window.location = "/pending";
     }
     else if(x==2){
        window.location = "/approved";
     }
     else if(x==3){
        window.location = "/denied";
    }
     else if(x==4){
        window.location = "/list";
     }
}
```

Upon selecting it will go to the specified url but the value of the combobox will return to value 0. Do you have any idea to make the selected value of the combobox to remain? Thanks.

Comment: by the way, i am using the same html page for all specified url above.

Comment: (O.T.) Why don't you simply use `<option value="/pending">Pending</option>` ?

Comment: well, you can either use regex to get the URL and set the select value accordingly on page load, or save the value in a cookie before you navigate, and on page load get the cookie and set the value

Comment: What do you mean by "make the selected value of the combobox to remain"? If you're navigating to another page, that value is gone unless you pass it as a parameter.

Comment: yes, ive been doing that one a while ago but my concern is that upon executing the url the value of the combo box will go back to "select status"

Answer (score 0):

You can use some item in Query String and upon page load, check the value of that item and set the selected item of the combo box accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

See corrected code below:

```
var select_element = document.getElementById('module-box');

select_element.onchange = function(e){
    if (!e)
        var e = window.event;
    var svalue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
      if(svalue==1){
        window.location = "/pending";
     }
     else if(svalue==2){
        window.location = "/approved";
     }
     else if(svalue==3){
        window.location = "/denied";
    }
     else if(svalue==4){
        window.location = "/list";
      }
}
```

Check this link for [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6f0anz67/)

Comment: it didn't work. I visit the demo and it doesn't alert anything.

Comment: Sorry I've send you the old link. the correct link is http://jsfiddle.net/6f0anz67/

Comment: it will go to the specified url but the value of the combobox will go back to  "select status".